# Sending an array through action link or url action and accept in route table in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

is it possible to send an array through action link or url action and accept in route table? If possible please guide me
controller code is

```
 public ActionResult subCategories(string mainCategory, string subCategory)
    {
    var fullPath = string.Concat(mainCategory, "/", subCategory);
    var id = _db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(p => p.FullPath == fullPath);
    ViewBag.urlPath = id.FullPath;
    var categories = _db.Products.Where(p => p.CategoryID == id.ID);
    return View("CategoryDetail", categories);
    }
```

View code is

```
<a style="color: #333333" href="/productdetail/@ViewBag.urlPath/@Nname">@item.Name</a>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While there's a wealth of information here, this site is not a code writing service. If you have a go yourself and post up what you've tried, people will be able to help you. [Look here for tips on writing a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) && [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Usman i was sending the list through ViewBag from controller to view for href as usual but my question is is it possible to send an array through href and accept it in route table?

Comment: can you show your controller? or can you show what you have tried?

Comment: What array are you talking about? Your method just has 2 `string` parameters - there is no array in your question

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes sir. In the place of two string parameters i want to accept an array and pass it to view bag for the href in my view

Comment: @mmushtaq sir i have updated my question. Please see if you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with `Json` let suppose i have array

```
ViewBag.array = new[] {"test1", "test2", "test3"};
```

so my view would be something like

```
@Html.ActionLink("link","test",new {array= Json.Encode(ViewBag.array) })
```

`Json.Encode` will convert this array to `json string`

and my test action will be like this

```
 public ActionResult test (string array)
        {
            string[] result = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<string[]>(array);

            return View();

        }
```

`Json.Decode<string[]>` will convert this `json string` back to `string[]` array

Comment: thanks for the answer but how to accept it in route table?

Comment: it will send a `GET` request means you dont need to add anything to routing table